# SQL inner join to the same table, on multiple columns, multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i have a table to save relationships of sql views

```
**ID**  VIEW1 VIEW2 COLUMN          RELATIONSHIP
**1**   1     2     SalesOrderID    INNER JOIN
**5**   1     3     SalesOrderID    INNER JOIN
**6**   2     4     ProductID       INNER JOIN
```

to build the relationship between view 4 and 3 I have to use ID 1 row for the intermediate reference, is there a posible way in MSSQL where I can accomplish this task

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: or is there a possible way to build relationships between mssql views

Comment: Relational databases are expected to have static schema (tables, columns, relations). So, to generate the query based on rules stored in a table you'll have to use dynamic SQL - construct the text of the query programmatically and run it using `sp_executesql` or `EXEC`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you would need something like this:

```
select v3.*, v4.*
from View1 as v1
    inner join View2 as v2 on v2.SalesOrderID = v1.SalesOrderID
    inner join View3 as v3 on v3.SalesOrderID = v1.SalesOrderID
    inner join View4 as v4 on v4.ProductID = v2.ProductID
```

-or (works for inner joins only)-

```
select v3.*, v4.*
from View1 as v1
    ,View2 as v2 
    ,View3 as v3
    ,View4 as v4
where
    v2.SalesOrderID = v1.SalesOrderID
    and v3.SalesOrderID = v1.SalesOrderID
    and v4.ProductID = v2.ProductID
```

As Vladimir Baranov suggested in the comment above above - if you need to build this select programmatically (that is your data in *table to save relationships of sql views* changes over time) you would have to deal with dynamic SQL.